# Springboot: Cannot register user

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am trying to create a registration page. Even though I am submitting the form, the data isn't being inserted in the postgresql user_table. Logging in works if I insert the data into the table manually. I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong.

register.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>Sign Up</title>
        <link href="webjars/bootstrap/5.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
         <div class="container col-xl-10 col-xxl-8 px-4 py-5">
            <div class="row align-items-center g-lg-5 py-5">
              
              <div class="col-md-10 mx-auto col-lg-5">
                <form class="p-4 p-md-5 border rounded-3 bg-light" th:action="@{/process_register}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
                  <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="UserName" th:field="*{username}">
                    <label for="floatingInput">User Name</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="FirstName" th:field="*{firstName}">
                    <label for="floatingInput">First Name</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="LastName" th:field="*{lastName}">
                    <label for="floatingInput">Last Name</label>
                  </div>    
                  <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com" th:field="*{email}">
                    <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password" th:field="*{password}">
                    <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
                  </div>
                  
                  <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-info" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
                  <hr class="my-4">
                  <small class="text-muted">If you already have an account, <a href="/">log in</a>.</small>
                  
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
         
         
        <script src="webjars/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="webjars/bootstrap/5.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

TwitterController.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;


@Controller
public class TwitterController{
    
    private UserRepository userRepo;
    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model) {
        //model.addAttribute("message", "Welcome to spring!");
        return "index";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/testing")
    public String testing(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Welcome to spring boot!");
        return "testing";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/register")
    public String signup(Model model) {
        User user = new User();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "register";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login(Model model) {
        return "login";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/process_register")
    public String processRegister(User user) {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        String encodedPassword = encoder.encode(user.getPassword());
        user.setPassword(encodedPassword);
        
        userRepo.save(user);
        
        return "register_success";
    }
```

User.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.Collection;


@Entity
@Table(name = "user_table")
public class User implements UserDetails{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    
    
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    
    public String getFirstName() {
        return fname;
    }
    
    public void setFirstName(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }
    
    public String getLastName() {
        return lname;
    }
    
    public void setLastName(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }
    
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
 
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }
 
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
 
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", username=" + username + ", password=" + password + "fname=" + fname + "lname=" + lname + "email=" + email + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public Set<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
        return authorities;
    }

    
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>{
    public User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

UserDetailsService.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@Service
public class UserDetailsService implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService{
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;
 
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
 
        User user = repository.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }
 
        return user;
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Twitter-clone</name>
    <description>Making a twitter clone</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        

        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Create a `UserService` and put the logic that you have in your controller in there. Make that service `@Transactional` and use the service **not** the repository from the controller. Basically it doesn't work due to lack of transactions, without a transaction you cannot persist anything in the database.

Comment: I don't think it is this, it looks like what was happening was the HTTPRequest was being blocked by the SecurityConfiguration. While I was able to send a request, it still isn't registering because the id is null.

Comment: The id should be `null` because it is a new user, the id will be assigned after saving. This has nothing to do with blocking the request by spring security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SecurityConfiguration is blocking the HTTPRequest. The other problem that I was having afterwards was that insertion still was not working. The user_table did not have an auto-increment id, and thus returned null and could not be inserted like that. Solution was either to change the hibernation settings or update user_table to auto-increment for the id.

Answer (score 0):

the annotation @Repository is missing in the interface UserRepository, also you should autowire this dependency by adding the annotation @Autowired in the field of dependency declaration in class TwitterController

Comment: I added Repository to UserRepository and Autowired to the userRepo in TwitterController. Still does not insert data in the user_table.

Comment: Adding `@Repository` to an interface is useless, especially if that interface is a Spring Data repository. Spring Data uses different mechanism to detect the repositories. Also if it wouldn't be detected the application would crash at startup **not** fail with not saving data.